# Glyphicons in Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, glyphicons, font-awesome-4

I am using Bootstrap 4. I would like to use Glyphicon in [Datatable](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css). I included [font-awsome](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css).

My CSS code is like below

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting::after, table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc::after, table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc::after, table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled::after, table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled::after {
content: "\e252" !important;
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 3px;
vertical-align: middle;
font-weight: 900;
```

}

But I am getting output like below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Font Awesome is missing the font files. If you look into the `font-awesome.css` file you will see it is expecting a fonts folder in its parent directory.

```
@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0'); ...
```

Expected folder structure -

```
|- css
|-- bootstrap-4.css
|-- font-awesome.css
|- fonts
|-- font-awesome.eot
|-- font-awesome.ttf
|-- ...
```